# Reservar memoria con malloc y avanzar el puntero ¿es válido?

Tags: c, punteros

Me ha surgido la duda a la hora de usar memoria dinámica, referente a cual seria una buena forma de gestionarla, dejo a continuación los dos casos que he probado para ver cual seria el mas correcto y si ninguno de los dos lo es me digan ustedes que cosas debería buscar:

En este primer caso simplemente declaro un puntero, le asigno una dirección con `malloc` y a partir de ahí uso puntero++ para extender la memoria, (este es el que menos me convence pues al usar ++ en un puntero realmente no se que pasa si lo saben ustedes me gustaría que me lo explicaran) supongo que realmente se hace una asignación de memoria pero queda como en el aire e inaccesible si no es volviendo al principio y haciendo ++ otra vez. También al final al liberar la memoria si hago un bucle para liberar todas las posiciones que he rellenado después de la primera que asigno con `malloc()` me da un error en free(), he leído que esto es debido a que `free()` solo libera memoria asignada con `malloc()` y por tanto las siguientes asignadas con ++ no cuentan, de esta forma si hago `free(head)` solo liberara la primera posición de memoria no?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i = 0,j;

    int *head = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *newItem = head;

    while (1) {

        cout << "dame el numero " << i + 1;
        cin >> *newItem;

        if (*newItem == 9)
            break;

        newItem++;
        i++;
    }

    *newItem = '\0';
    cout << head << endl;
    newItem = head;

    for(j =0;j<i;j++) {

        cout << *newItem << ", ";
        newItem++;

    }

        free(head);

    return 0;
}
```

En el segundo caso creo un struct en el que almaceno el numero y un puntero al siguiente elemento que le corresponde a este "array dinamico" de esta forma cada vez que leo un nuevo numero creo una nueva direccion de memoria con `malloc` para mi nuevo elemento y se la paso al anterior para que sepa donde esta su siguiente, asi soluciono los problemas de saber donde estan las direcciones de memoria contigua y el tema de liberar memoria, pues cada direccion ahora es asignada por `malloc`, entonces aqui me pregunto si realmente conviene hacer el struct para tenerlo todo organizado y asumir el coste de memoria y rendimiento que supone tener un array cuya finalidad es almacenar enteros pero que para ello almacena una estructura con dos atributos.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct item {
    int number;
    struct item *next;
};

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    float numero;

//  struct item *head = (struct item *) malloc(sizeof(struct item));
    struct item *head;
    head = NULL;
    struct item *prev = head, *newItem;

    while (1) { //el 1 en el while se considra siempre cierto (bucle infinito)
        cout << "dame el numero " << i+1;
        cin >> numero;
        if (numero == 9)
            break;

        newItem = (struct item *) malloc(sizeof(struct item));
        newItem->number = numero;
        newItem->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newItem;
        } else
            prev->next = newItem;
        prev = newItem;
        i++;
    }
    cout << head << endl;
    prev = head;

    while (prev != NULL) {
        cout << prev->number << ", ";
        prev = prev->next;
    }

    prev = head;
    struct item *aux;
    while (prev != NULL) {
        aux=prev->next;
        free(prev);
        prev=aux;
    }
}
```

PD: mi duda realmente es de C pero uso cout y cin por ser mas comodos a la hora de hacer pruebas y dado que C++ contiene a C debo suponer que no hay problema.

Comment: Estas usando `malloc` pero pones c++ y también usas `cout`. C y C++ son lenguajes diferentes, para que la respuesta se ajuste mejor a lo que necesitas, edita la pregunta por favor y con gusto te contestamos

Comment: @DavidIsla se puede usar `malloc` y `free` en C++, pero sin duda no es lo habitual ni lo aconsejado.

Comment: Latiagertrudis, tu problema es que pides memoria para un solo entero pero después asignas enteros en posiciones de memoria que no has pedido... lo sorprendente es que no te falle antes.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Entonces la segunda opción esta bien o realmente hay una forma de hacerlo sin usar un struct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> En este primer caso simplemente declaro un puntero, le asigno una dirección con malloc y a partir de ahí uso puntero++ para extender la memoria, (este es el que menos me convence pues al usar ++ en un puntero realmente no se que pasa si lo saben ustedes me gustaría que me lo explicaran)

En este código:

```
int *head = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)); // (1)
int *newItem = head; // (2)

while (1) {

    cout << "dame el numero " << i + 1;
    cin >> *newItem;

    if (*newItem == 9)
        break;

    newItem++; // (3)
    i++;
}
```

Sucede lo siguiente:

1. Haces una reserva de memoria para almacenar un entero. **uno solo**
2. Creas un segundo puntero que apunta a la reserva anterior
3. El puntero pasa a apuntar a la memoria contigua a la reservada

En el punto 3 te estás saliendo de la memoria reservada para tal fin. Cualquier operación de escritura que hagas entonces sobreescribirá valores aleatorios (porque no sabes que hay ahí almacenado) y tu programa se volverá inestable (o se morirá si intentas escribir en memoria que no te pertenece).

En este caso quizás lo más sensato es pedirle al usuario que te diga cuántos elementos quiere introducir y hacer una reserva acorde al número introducido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numElementos;
    puts("Dime el numero de elementos: ");
    scanf("%d",&numElementos);

    int* head = malloc(numElementos*sizeof(int));
    int* newItem = head;

    for( int i=1; i<=numElementos; i++, newItem++)
    {
        printf("dame el numero %d:",i);
        scanf("%d,newItem);

        if (*newItem == 9)
            break;
    }

    newItem = head;
    for(int i=0; i<numElementos; i++, newItem++) {
        printf("%d, ",*newItem);
    }

    free(head);

    return 0;
}
```

> También al final al liberar la memoria si hago un bucle para liberar todas las posiciones que he rellenado después de la primera que asigno con malloc() me da un error en free()

No te está dando un error en free sino que, como te he explicado en el punto anterior, el Sistema Operativo detecta un intento de escritura en memoria que no pertenece al proceso y lo mata para evitar que corrompa la memoria. Es un mecanismo de protección de los Sistemas medianamente modernos.

> En el segundo caso creo un struct en el que almaceno el numero y un puntero al siguiente elemento que le corresponde a este "array dinamico"

Acabas de inventar la lista enlazada simple... bueno, casi.

> aqui me pregunto si realmente conviene hacer el struct para tenerlo todo organizado y asumir el coste de memoria y rendimiento que supone tener un array cuya finalidad es almacenar enteros pero que para ello almacena una estructura con dos atributos.

Para el ejemplo que propones la respuesta es no. Y no por el coste de memoria o de rendimiento, que en tu caso es despreciable, sino por lo engorroso que resulta el código.

Cada posible solución suele estar enfocada a las necesidades propias de cada momento. Así, por ejemplo, un algoritmo de ordenación que funcione muy bien con grandes volúmenes de valores suele comportarse de forma torpe con colecciones pequeñas y viceversa. No suele haber una solución universal. No en programación.

Para lo que pretendes puedes optar por usar `realloc`, que te permite incrementar el tamaño de la reserva y gestionar únicamente una reserva de memoria:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0,j;

    int* head = 0;
    int numElements = 0;

    while (true) {

        numElements ++;
        int* temp = realloc(head,numElements *sizeof(int));
        if( temp == 0 )
        {
          // Error al reservar la memoria
        }
        head = temp;
        int* tail = head+numElements-1;

        printf("dame el numero %d: ", numElements);
        scanf("%d",tail);

        if (*tail== 9)
            break;
    }

    for( int i=0; i<numElements; i++ )
      printf("%d, ",head[i]);

    free(head);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tan completa, se me ha olvidado comentar que esto era para un ejercicio mas grande en C y solo se me permite usar malloc y free (uso cout y cin solo para hacer pruebas pues me resulta menos engorroso que printf y scanf, pero el ejercicio luego debe ser completamente en C), sabiendo esto la lista enlazada que nombras es la mejor opción?

Comment: @latiagertrutis Quizás debieras reformular la pregunta y poner el enunciado de lo que tienes que hacer... y quitar toda referencia de C++ para no crear confusión

Answer (score 9):

> En este primer caso simplemente declaro un puntero, le asigno una dirección con `malloc` y a partir de ahí uso puntero++ para extender la memoria.

Este es tu primer fallo de concepto, incrementar un puntero (`puntero++`) no extiende la memoria que este puntero gestiona si no que hace que apunte a otra dirección, permíteme ilustrarlo:
[image]
Cuando haces `malloc`, estas pidiendo memoria dinámica, en concreto pides `sizeof(int)` bytes, que en muchos sistemas corresponde con 4 bytes, así puedes ver que en la RAM has pedido cuatro cajitas de memoria y `puntero` apunta ahí.

Cuando incrementas un puntero (`puntero++`) avanzas tantas posiciones como tamaño maneje el puntero, en este caso como el puntero es a entero (`int`) avanzarás cuatro posiciones:
[image]
El problema es que la posición a la que apunta `puntero` después de incrementarlo no ha sido reservada (ni con `malloc` ni con `new`) por lo tanto no es legal que la uses; al hacer `cin >> *puntero` el programa podría finalizar por corrupción de memoria.

Por el mismo motivo, cuando intentas liberar dicha memoria el programa falla:

> Al liberar la memoria si hago un bucle para liberar todas las posiciones que he rellenado después de la primera que asigno con `malloc()` me da un error en `free()`

¡No puedes liberar memoria que no has pedido! Sólo has pedido el primer entero (`int`) y los subsiguientes son memoria que no te pertenece y no ha sido pedida mediante `malloc`.

---

Una vez explicados los conceptos básicos, vamos a aclarar otras cosas:

> ¿Realmente conviene hacer el `struct` para tenerlo todo organizado y asumir el coste de memoria y rendimiento que supone tener un `array` cuya finalidad es almacenar enteros pero que para ello almacena una estructura con dos atributos?

Si, es la manera de hacerlo.

> Uso `cout` y `cin` por ser mas cómodos a la hora de hacer pruebas y dado que C++ contiene a C debo suponer que no hay problema.

Si, hay problema. Problema porque conceptualmente son distintos y operan de diferente manera. C++ no contiene C, es compatible con C pero no lo contiene.